# What is this leaf / organic style font used in the Rosa Mística logo?

Tags: font-identification

Here's a font I happened upon in a logo on Behance:
[image: Rosa Mística logo]

I've been looking for something similar to add to my collection for a while now, I had the need for one some time ago when designing a logo for a landscape design firm but couldn't really find anything suitable.

I do have a font called "Leave" - sorry, I can't tell you where I got it form, I honestly can't remember - that is similar in style but squarer edges and more rigid. The one used in this logo though is quite stunning, I know at least the accent above the first lower case 'i' must be custom but I'm hoping someone can identify the font itself.

WhatTheFont didn't come up with anything useful. If you know it or something similar that'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not an exact match, but feels very much like Diavlo http://www.exljbris.com/diavlo.html

Comment: I agree with @DA01 - it does feel a lot like Diavlo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks pretty close to [Cocon font](http://www.fonts.com/font/fontfont/ff-cocon/collection) -

[image]

Comment: .. and that cute acute is not even custom!